# WPF Print Problem

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

When i select Microsoft XPS Document Writer as Printer, my output is perfect but when i select my HP 1020 printer machine, the printer outputs blank copy...Following is the code....

```
private void printButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PrintInvoice pi = new PrintInvoice();
        pi.DataContext = this.DataContext;
        PrintDialog printDlg = new System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog();
        if (printDlg.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            pi.Margin = new Thickness(30);

            //now print the visual to printer to fit on the one page.
            printDlg.PrintVisual(pi, "First Fit to Page WPF Print");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried simplifying PrintInvoice to see if they are any elements that are causing issues with the HP printer?

Comment: PrintInvoice is a page and it's output in Microsoft XPS Document Writer is perfect.

Comment: I checked to see the pi.ActualHeight and pi.ActualWidth for both the cases. (When HP printer Machine is selected ) Height = 0 and Width = NaN.... (When Microsoft XPS Document Writer is selected) Height = 950 and Width = NaN 

Can be this be the cause and whats the reason and solution for this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This could be caused by a number of different things.  There are a few steps that you can add which, when performed correctly, may [cause the flying men to return with goods and knowledge.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult)

First, you should scale to the printed page (code from [a2zdotnet](http://www.a2zdotnet.com/View.aspx?id=66)):

```
System.Printing.PrintCapabilities capabilities = 
    printDlg.PrintQueue.GetPrintCapabilities(printDlg.PrintTicket);

 //get scale of the print wrt to screen of WPF visual
 double scale = Math.Min(capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth / this.ActualWidth, capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight /
                this.ActualHeight);

 //Transform the Visual to scale
 this.LayoutTransform = new ScaleTransform(scale, scale);

 //get the size of the printer page
 Size sz = new Size(capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth, capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight);

 //update the layout of the visual to the printer page size.
 this.Measure(sz);
 this.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginWidth, capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginHeight), sz));

  //now print the visual to printer to fit on the one page.
  printDlg.PrintVisual(this, "Code ganked from http://www.a2zdotnet.com/View.aspx?id=66");
```

The cargo-cult code is in the Measure and Arrange steps.  Often, if you call Measure and pass in a `new Size(Double.MaxValue, Double.MaxValue)` that's all you need to do.

The second ritual involves bumping the Dispatcher.

```
visual.DataContext = foo;
Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)()=>{;}); // bamp
// print here
```

Try these and see if it helps.

Comment: I had the same problem, and it still didn't print. Bumping the dispatcher didn't change anything, but I managed to solve the problem by adding a call to the UpdateLayout() method on my control

Answer (score 0):

this `XAML` does the trick in some situations

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
  <... Name="myPrintElement" />
</ScrollViewer >
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).